# How does the total derivative formula work?

Tags: derivatives, partial-derivative

Fellas, I have just learned this formula for computing the total derivative of a function $f(x, y)$ with respect to $x$ from its partial derivatives as follows:

$\frac{d}{dx}f(x,y)=\frac{∂f}{∂x}+\frac{∂f}{∂y}\frac{dy}{dx}$

But I can't understand why this equality is true. I have looked for proofs of this, but they are very technical proofs, hard to understand. Can anyone explain to me the basic intuition behind it?

Comment: It's simple use of chain rule. $\frac{df}{dx} = \frac{\partial f}{\partial x}\frac{dx}{dx}+\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}\frac{dy}{dx}$. Notice that $\frac{dx}{dx} = 1$

Comment: That's what I don't understand. Since when does the chain rule involve addition? I would understand that formula if $f(x,y)=g(x)+h(y)$, but that's not a condition for $f(x, y)$, is it. It could be something like $f(x,y)=x^2+xy+y^2$

Comment: That's the higher dimensional analogue of chain rule. $\frac{df(x,y,z)}{dt} = \frac{\partial f}{\partial x}\frac{dx}{dt}+\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}\frac{dy}{dt}+\frac{\partial f}{\partial z}\frac{dz}{dt}$ and so on.

Comment: Oh, ok. And how do you get from the 1 dimensional chain rule to the higher dimensional chain rule? Why are those terms added?

Comment: Terms are added because the dimension is increasing. You don't get from $1$ dimensional chain rule to $n$ dimensional chain rule, you prove it on its own. Look up the proof.

Comment: I looked up the multivariable chain rule and now I understand, thanks!